# Unable to add actionlistener from another class

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Seems like I completely do not understand how these things work.....I have a class that extends JPanel and implements Actionlistener and then I want to add that to a class that extends JFrame....I can't get this to work.....

```
public class testPanel extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JButton someBtn;

public testPanel(JButton someBtn){
    this.someBtn = someBtn;
    add(someBtn);
    someBtn.addActionListener(this);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource() == someBtn)
        System.out.println("this worked");
}

}
```

2nd class file

```
public class JavaApplication3 extends JFrame{

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
JButton button;

public JavaApplication3(){
    super("blah");
    JFrame p = new testPanel(button);
    add(p);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    new JavaApplication3();
}
}
```

Comment: You have not initialised the button instance variable...

Comment: Normally you'd want to include the actual error you get.

Comment: Your example can't work, both classes extend from JFrame

Answer (score 1):

This line in `testPanel` must surely throw an exception:

```
add(someBtn);
```

As the reference `someBtn` is empty...

You never initialized the `button` instance variable in the `JavaApplication3` class, bzut have used the variable in the constructor of the `testPanel` class.

However, you'd want to get the inverse of this flow:

1. create the button inside the `testPanel` class
2. if you'd like to get the reference from the `JavaApplication3` class -- you'l need a getter in the testPanel class

Example:

```
public class testPanel extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JButton someBtn; //consider using private

    public testPanel(){
        this.someBtn = new JButton(); //add correct constructor here
        add(someBtn);
        someBtn.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public JButton getSomeBtn() {
        reeturn someBtn;
    }
//... rest comes here
}



public class JavaApplication3 extends JFrame{

    JButton button;

    public JavaApplication3(){
        super("blah");
        JFrame p = new testPanel();
        button  = p.getSomeBtn(); //this is the important line
        add(p);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    //... rest comes here    
}
```

**Sidenote:** use the Java naming convention: Class Names Start With Capitals...